# Infinite moving text with scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want make a moving infinite text like this text(We are trusted by over 28,000...) in this [link](http://preview.themeforest.net/item/ernest-creative-portfolio-template/full_screen_preview/35613977?_ga=2.235917953.1410740607.1642603474-1415504948.1642603474) . I already tried something but I have not reached exactly what I want. It is close but not infinite.

```
<h1 class="deneme display-1 " id="movingtext">We are trusted by over 28,000 clients to power stunning websites.We are trusted by over 28,000 clients to power stunning websites.</h1>
```

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  var elemen = document.getElementById("movingtext");
  elemen.style = "left:-450px"
  var rect = elemen.getBoundingClientRect();
  var rect1 = rect.left;
  var scrolled = window.scrollY;
  var deg = (rect1 + scrolled) / 1.8;

  elemen.style = "left:" + deg + "px";
  console.log(rect.left, rect.right);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the following screenshots this is not infinite either:

[first row with "We are trusted by over 28,000..."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk4cy.jpg)
and [second row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F75r3.jpg)

It's just that on normal screen you can't reach the end of the element.

You can accomplish something similar by adding an listener on scroll and transforming the element you want to be moved retative to `window.pageYOffset` value.

Something like:

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const movingtext = document.getElementById("movingtext");
  const scrolled = window.pageYOffset;
  //feel free to play with this value to change the speed of the transform ( the `* 3` part)
  const left = scrolled * 3;

  movingtext.style.transform = `translate3d(-${left}px, 0px, 0px)`;
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 300vh;
  padding-top: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.infinite-text {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<h1 class="infinite-text" id="movingtext">We are trusted by over 28,000 clients to power stunning websites.We are trusted by over 28,000 clients to power stunning websites.</h1>
</div>
```

Please note that this is a draft. You might want to play with sizes and speed of transform or other attributes.

Please note that for this example the container has `max-width: 100vw;` and `overflow: hidden` (so it won't display a scrollbar for the element that is bigger than the screen), and the element itself has `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: Thank you.I deleted the "-" for other way but this time text begin from 0. <script>
        window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
            const movingtext = document.getElementById("movingtext2");
            const scrolled = window.pageYOffset;
            //feel free to play with this value to change the speed of the transform ( the `* 3` part)
            const left = scrolled *1.5;

            movingtext.style.transform = `translate3d(${left}px, 0px, 0px)`;
        })
            
    </script>

Comment: Great to hear it helped! If this answered your problem please consider accepting the answer (this will also help other users now that the question is solved) :)